# Can't kill service from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I start service from activity which are sending data throught socket to server. When service is started in it's `onCreate()` method I also set alarm with `setExact()` method. My problem is that when `onReceive()` in `BroadcastReceiver` is called I want to stop service, which is working corectly but it is also immedeately started again. Service is stopped with next code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, SocketService.class);
context.stopService(i);
```

which work correctly if it is called from Activity. When `BroadcastReceiver` is executed, no activity is binded to that service so it should stop without immedeately recreating.

Answer (score 2):

Your service.

```
private Intent myservice;
```

Start your service on method onCreate()

```
  myservice = new Intent(this, myservice.class);
  startService(myservice);
```

also you can start your service with handler.

And for stop use handler.

```
    private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case 1:
                   stopService(myservice);
                break;
            default:
                Log.d("STOP", msg.what + " ? ");
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

for use handler on BroadcastReceiver make this

```
handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
```